# problem in displaying table if all the fields which are submitted are not empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have three fields which are related to each other and i am getting 2nd value after submitting the 1st varibale and 3rd value after submitting 2nd field

I have these 3 fields which are interrelated to each other

```
<?php 

    $courtname='';

    if(!empty($_POST['court_name']))
    {
      $courtname=$_POST['court_name'];
     }


    $category='';

    if(!empty($_POST['category']))
    {
      $category=$_POST['category'];
    }

    $lawyer_name='';

    if(!empty($_POST['lawyer_name']))
    {
      $lawyer_name=$_POST['lawyer_name'];
    }


?>
```

And i want to show this div part only when all the above 3 fields are submitted

```
<?php 
if($lawyer_name!=="" && $courtname!=="" && $category!==""){?>
    <div>
!--- Some Code ----!

    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

But this if condition is not working ..and div part is showing after submitting 2 fields ..Its not checking for 3rd condition .

I have also used

```
<?php  if(!empty($_POST['court_name']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['lawyer_name'])   ){ ?>
```

but that's also not working.

Comment: Try with `!=` instead of `!==`

Comment: is that code on the same file ?

Comment: yes its the same code

Comment: @alanfcm i have treid != also but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try with  :

```
<?php  
  if( isset($_POST['court_name']) && isset($_POST['category']) && !isset($_POST['lawyer_name'])   ){ 
  // code
  }

?>
```

Comment: that's also not working..Its not showing the div part even after submitting all the fields